# jquery-ui nested accordion not working properly with twitter bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying trying to create a nested accordion out of twitter-bootstrap panels. But the problem is, both the parent and child accordions are being affected (collapsed/opened) together when I click on either one. Is something wrong with my header selector?

my html:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Outer Panel</div>
    <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Inner Panel</div>
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".panel").accordion({header:'.panel-heading',collapsible:true});
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the `header` option would need to be `>.panel-heading` to affect only the current level.